# track form submission using DTM

Tags: adobe-analytics

I would like to track the form submission using DTM. If we use event based tracking how can I check if all the form fields are validated before tracking submission button? How these types of logic are added in DTM?

Comment: How do you currently validate your form? The correct answer should be "With server-side logic" in which case you cannot use DTM to detect when this happens.

Comment: currently we are doing it through javascript in the form page. I have a new requirement and thought of using DTM if we have the option. If we don't have any option then i need to go back to javascript.

Comment: okay well you shouldn't be validating your form with javascript, because it is not secure. A malicious user/bot can easily circumvent that.  But assuming that you are sticking to it and that's all there is to it.. DTM cannot detect when your separate js form validation has occured.  But, you can replicate that in DTM (though it'd be in a custom code box as js all the same)

Comment: Or, you put a call to DTM within your current js validation logic.  Make a DTM direct call rule named "form submitted" or whatever and then in your current js validation logic, at the point where the form is validated, call `_satellite.track("form submitted")` and then pop your tracking within the direct call rule.

Comment: 2nd option sounds simpler. Let me try this and i will come back to you with my questions. Thank you so much for your time. I appreciate it.